# Bashrc disable-ing all but a given command for a given user

Tags: shell, account-restrictions

Is it possible to have `bashrc` grab every single command the user types, save for those containing a given word?

Like the way you can use aliases to change what the user meant, you can alias for instance 'cd' to nothing. that way the user can't apply that command anymore.

Maybe that way you can have a given user only able to apply one command?

Comment: Are you looking for `chroot`?

Comment: i dont know, does that achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I restrict a user to use special programs?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42543/can-i-restrict-a-user-to-use-special-programs)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate; that question is more focused on graphical applications, whereas this one is explicitly about terminal programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need users to access files remotely with sftp or rsync, but not be able to run shell commands, then use [`rssh` or `scponly`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9837/do-you-need-a-shell-for-scp/9839#9839).

If you need users to be able to run only a few programs, set a [restricted shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_shell) for them, such as `rbash` or `rksh`. In a restricted shell, `PATH` cannot be changed and only programs in the path can be executed. Beware not to allow programs that allow the user to run other programs, such as the `!` or `|` command in `vi`. Access to files remains controlled by the file permissions.

Comment: Ok this rssh stuff is absolutely brilliant. But is there any way to limit the rsync'ing to only the home folder of this limited rssh account?

Comment: @HermannIngjaldsson Yes, though it does take a bit of manual setup. See the `CHROOT` file in the rssh documentation.

Comment: What do you think about restricting clients access via ssh-keygen as talked about here by mdpc: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87983/how-to-securely-allow-scp-but-not-ssh/88028#88028?

Comment: @HermannIngjaldsson Restricting the command in `authorized_keys`? Yes, that's possible. It gives you finer control: you can have different keys allowing different commands. Filtering the command is tricky; it works well if you want e.g. to only allow sftp, less well if you also want to allow scp and rsync.

Comment: where is the CHROOT file in the rssh documentation?

Comment: @HermannIngjaldsson It's in the source archive, and presumably your distribution installs it wherever it installs the documentation. For example, on Debian/Ubuntu/Mint/…, it's in `/usr/share/doc/rssh`.

Answer (score 1):

Some shells (ksh, f.e.) have restricted mode, in this mode they will not execute anything outside `$PATH`.